# How to model "family and others" thing?

Tags: python, django, oop

I need to model family, parents, children and ordinary people entities. How can I do that? 
Obviously, I could create 4 or even 5 different classess: family, 2 for both parents, one for a children and one for people.
But I think there's redundancy in this approach. On the other hand, if I introduce a field "type" being either family, mother, etc..., then I'd have to create also nullable field-reference for family and maybe other stuff.

Your advice?

Comment: No classes. Single 'FamilMember' namedtuple and that's it

Comment: that's awfully depends on what you intend to do with it, does mother and father have different roles (and methods)? can a family have no parents? only 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I think it would make sense to simply have two classes, for example

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Family:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []
        self.parents = []
```

Then `Family.children` and `Family.parents` could be lists of `Person` objects, where you could have any number of children or parents.

You could also add some more attributes to `Person` if you wanted to store relationships, like a `Person` could have members of their `.siblings` or `.parents` or `.children`

Comment: What about `self.spouse`?

Comment: You might also subclass `Person` for different types of family members, if the complexity of your model warrants it.